# Script para banco postgres

Tags: postgresql, script, batch, psql

Criei esse script, para limpar a tabela do banco e zerar *id*'s.

Funciona, mas não do jeito certo

Ele roda e autentica no **psql**. mas ao invés de rodar os comando **sql** ele somente abre o **psql**.

Se alguém tiver uma saída desde já agradeço.

```
@echo off

set PGUSER=####
set PGPASSWORD=#####

echo on

"D:\Programas\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres pauliceia delete from bairros;
"D:\Programas\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres pauliceia alter table bairros AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: o script q vc diz, é um .Bat ? veja a sintaxe: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer com que o `psql` execute o SQL você precisa utilizar o parâmetro `-c` e informar a string com o(s) comando(s).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Alterando o seu código de exemplo, ficaria conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
@echo off

set PGUSER=#### set PGPASSWORD=#####

echo on

"D:\Programas\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c 'delete from bairros;' -c 'alter table bairros AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;' pauliceia
```